# Get the container ID when triggered from a docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I get the docker ID that just got deployed when triggered from the docker file?

What I would like to do is add some command in the docker file which will provide the container ID of the instance that just got deployed:

> "Example echo $CONTAINERID"

This will be further used for container maintenance.

Any leads on this one are appreciated

My Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wine1.7 && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nvidia-361 && \
    apt-get autoremove -y --purge software-properties-common && \
    apt-get autoremove -y --purge && \
    apt-get clean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

  RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash gaming
  USER gaming
  WORKDIR /home/gaming
  ENV HOME /home/gaming
  RUN wine wineboot --init
```

Comment: container ID from docker file...Do you know that you will get only an image from docker file but not container ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to build your Dockerfile and after it successfully build, you have to RUN it. Only a running container gets a container ID.

have you tried `docker ps` or `docker inspect`?

for example:

```
$ docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" <container_name>
756535dc6e9ab9b560f84c85063f55952273a23192641fc2756aa9721d9d1000
```